# Padding in PCX decoder

Tags: c#, image, image-processing

I've got a PCX decoder in C# (see below) that is meant to read in a Stream and output a Bitmap. It works when dealing with an image that has dimensions that are multiples of 8, and seems to work with most images that are less than 8bpp regardless of dimensions, but images with different dimensions become skewed in an unusal way (see [this link](http://www.gui-info.com/archive/ct.png) ). The pixels are all there, just it seems to be almost moved left in a weird way. The image is a valid PCX and opens in IrfanView and Paint.net.

Edit 1:

Okay, here's the result of quite a bit of testing: images with a byte-per-line value that divides by 8 (e.g. 316x256) decode fine, but images with an odd value don't. This is not true for all PCX files; it would seem that some (most?) images created in IrfanView work fine, but those I've found elsewhere do not. I was working on this some time ago, so I can't recall where they came from, I do know that images saved with the paint.net plug-in ([here](http://calormen.com/tmp/PcxFileTypeSrc.zip)) also reproduce this problem. I think it's likely due to a padding issue, either with them or my decoder, but the images to decode fine elsewhere so, it's likely I'm the one with the problem, I just can't see where :(

End of Edit 1.

My code for importing is here (there's a lot, but it's the whole decoding algorithm, minus the header, which is processed separately):

```
     public IntPtr ReadPixels(Int32 BytesPerScanline, Int32 ScanLines, Stream file)
     {
     //BytesPerScanLine is the taken from the header, ScanLines is the height and file is the filestream
        IntPtr pBits;

        Boolean bRepeat;
        Int32 RepeatCount;
        Byte ReadByte;

        Int32 Row = 0;
        Int32 Col = 0;

        Byte[] PCXData = new Byte[BytesPerScanline * ScanLines]; //BytesPerScanline * ScanLines);

        BinaryReader r = new BinaryReader(file);

        r.BaseStream.Seek(128, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        while (Row < ScanLines)
        {
            ReadByte = r.ReadByte();

            bRepeat = (0xc0 == (ReadByte & 0xC0));
            RepeatCount = (ReadByte & 0x3f);

            if (!(Col >= BytesPerScanline))
            {

                if (bRepeat)
                {
                    ReadByte = r.ReadByte();

                    while (RepeatCount > 0)
                    {
                        PCXData[(Row * BytesPerScanline) + Col] = ReadByte;

                        RepeatCount -= 1;
                        Col += 1;
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    PCXData[(Row * BytesPerScanline) + Col] = ReadByte;

                    Col += 1;
                }
            }

            if (Col >= BytesPerScanline)
            {
                Col = 0;
                Row += 1;
            }
        }

       pBits = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.AllocHGlobal(PCXData.Length);
       System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(PCXData, 0, pBits, PCXData.Length);

        return pBits;
    }
```

I've been advised that it might be an issue with padding, but I can't see where this may be in the code and I'm struggling to see how to understand where the padding is.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCX#Image_data_layout

Comment: So, I only read to the width*bits-per-pixel for each line, is this the same for files with 8bpp, because I will always have an even number of bits?

Comment: I don't know, the pcx image format is hopelessly obsolete.  It isn't clear what you do with the returned IntPtr.  My crystal ball says that the real problem is that you don't account for BitmapData.Stride.  Scanlines must start at an offset that is a multiple of 4.

Comment: This is my current method of calculating the stride:  int bytes = (width * bpp + 7) / 8; int stride = 4 * ((bytes + 3) / 4); You could be right, but I wouldn't know if this is wrong or not. The whole stride aspect of Bitmaps does confuse me slightly, I will admit.

Comment: Just don't do it this way.  Create the Bitmap first and use LockBits() to get a pointer to the pixel data.  Then copy the pixels.

Comment: Ok, so I've got a new bitmap with the width, height and pixelformat. Do I use Marshal.Copy to move my pointer into the Bitmap?